# Can I create a graph in c++ using STL?

Tags: c++, graph, stl, depth-first-search

Im a CS student, learning graphs algorithms theory (DFS, BFS, Dijkstra, Strongly connected components). My question is what is the easiest practical way to work with a graph DS in cpp: Is there any easy way to create a graph and run DFS on it? like an STL adjacency list and ready-to-run DFS using this adjacency list?

thanks :)

Comment: If you want something ready-made, there's [Boost Graph](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/libs/graph/doc/index.html)

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/graph-and-its-representations/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5205491/whats-the-difference-between-stl-and-c-standard-library

Comment: Please find a complete working example for an adjaceny graph here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57086336/string-searching-algorithm-that-uses-a-graph-c/57108650#57108650